# tmap::save_tmap function cannot save HTML file in folders other than the working directory

Tags: r, tmap

I am learning how to use the `tmap` package to generate a map and save it to an interactive HTML file. If I created a `tmap` object and save it to my working directory using the `save_tmap` function, I got a HTML file as expected. But if I change the directory to other paths, it generated an error message. Please see the following example.

```
# Load tmap package
library(tmap)
# Load example data
data(World)
# Create example map
example_map <- tm_shape(World, projection="longlat") + 
      tm_polygons() + 
      tm_layout("Long lat coordinates (WGS84)", 
                inner.margins = c(0, 0, .1, 0), title.size = .8)

# Save an HTML object
save_tmap(example_map, "example_map.html")
```

I will get the `example_map.html` in my working directory.

```
# Create a folder in the working directory
if (!dir.exists("tmap_folder")){
  dir.create("tmap_folder")
}

# Save the HTML object in "tmap_folder"
save_tmap(example_map, "tmap_folder/example_map.html")
```

It will not work. I will get the following error message

> Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
>   path[1]="tmap_folder": The system cannot find the file specified

Please share your thoughts if you have any ideas what could cause this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a struggle between normalizePath and Windows (see another example [here](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/issues/61)). Instead of using a relative path like `"tmap_folder/example_map.html"` try using an absolute path like `C:/users/ycw/tmap_folder/example_map.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option seems to be using the `here` package.  That way, you don't have to specify the full path and you code is likely to be more portable, play better with rstudio projects and Rmarkdown.

```
# Save the HTML object in "tmap_folder" with here package
library(here)
save_tmap(example_map, here("tmap_folder","example_map.html"))
```